# How to run "npm install" command for multiple sibling folders at once (from a parent folder path)?

Tags: npm-install

Let's say I have a folder in `D:` drive with multiple children as below...

```
|PARENT_FOLDER

--|CHILD_FOLDER_01
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_02
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_03
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_04
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_05
----|package.json
```

I need to install `node_modules` in all the Children folders.

```
|PARENT_FOLDER

--|CHILD_FOLDER_01
----|node_modules
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_02
----|node_modules
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_03
----|node_modules
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_04
----|node_modules
----|package.json

--|CHILD_FOLDER_05
----|node_modules
----|package.json
```

This can be achieved by running the below command

```
D:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER_01>npm install
D:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER_02>npm install
D:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER_03>npm install
D:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER_04>npm install
D:\PARENT_FOLDER\CHILD_FOLDER_05>npm install
```

But I want to do all the installations in a single go. If I want to do the installation of `node_modules` for all the folders in a single go, what command do I need to execute in the path mentioned below?

```
D:\PARENT_FOLDER>
```

I tried `npm install` in all the child folders individually. I expect a shortcut command so that I can execute installation of `node_modules` for all the sibling children's folders at a time.

### Update

In the PARENT_FOLDER's package.json file I wrote

```
"scripts": { 
   "allModulesInstall": "cd CHILD_FOLDER_01 && npm install && cd.. && 
                         cd CHILD_FOLDER_02 && npm install && cd.. && 
                         cd CHILD_FOLDER_03 && npm install && cd.. && 
                         cd CHILD_FOLDER_04 && npm install && cd.. && 
                         cd CHILD_FOLDER_05 && npm install" 
}
```

kind of syntax which has worked for me.

Is there anything that can be refactored in here?
FYI, I have multiple angular apps for which I am using this kind of installation procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do is

Setup a package.json in parent directory and add a script

```
"install": "(cd CHILD_FOLDER_01 && npm i ) ... and so on "
```

or just make a bash file which iterates through sub directories and install npm packages.

## install.sh

```
for dir in */; do                                                                                            
   (cd "$dir" && npm i)
done
```

## package.json

```
"install": "./install.sh"
```

also the brackets helps to access the directory without cd'ing it.

Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13802/execute-a-specific-command-in-a-given-directory-without-cding-to-it

Comment: In the `PARENT_FOLDER`'s `package.json` file I wrote ```"scripts": { "allModulesInstall": "cd CHILD_FOLDER_01 && npm install && cd.. && cd CHILD_FOLDER_02 && npm install && cd.. && cd CHILD_FOLDER_03 && npm install && cd.. && cd CHILD_FOLDER_04 && npm install && cd.. && cd CHILD_FOLDER_05 && npm install" }``` kinda syntax which worked for me. Is there anything that can be refactored in here? I am unable to use `./install.sh`. FYI, I have 8 different angular apps for which I am using this kind of installation procedure

Comment: you can run commands insidde (cd ./folder && npm i) here you don't have run `cd ..` also can you share what issue you were facing will running install.sh